# Need suggestion on best practive for git workflow

Tags: git, github

I want to ask something that might be simple but I need your advice since I'm not really familiar with git.

I have a website whose previous developer did version control with their private git repo (which I have access to). But the previous developer isn't working on it anymore and there's a new developer including me.

How do I close the web connection with the previous dev git repo, so they can't access my current web and push or pull the code? Then I want to setup a new git repo and connect it to current website.

I'm using Digital Ocean as my website server.

What I'm thinking is:

1. Pull all code to my git desktop.
2. Setup a new private git repo.
3. Push it from my git desktop to new repo.
4. Somehow pull it again to my site.

Is this correct?

But how do I remove the current web connection with the previous repo and recognize the new repo?

Comment: You're asking two questions here, which will likely get you in trouble with the mods - especially since you dont give any details about how your site is hosted.

Comment: I've answered the github part of your question, I suggest you edit your question to only address that part of your issue - and then create another question for the hosting related query - in which you will definitely need to provide more detail.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. i just revised my question, hopefully its not a problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github wise, your suggestion will work but you will lose all history on the existing code. *Forking* the repo is a better option as this will keep all the history and have the same effect. See https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Comment: Hi  thanks, as far as I know when you forking eventually you need to merge it with master branch to pull it to live website isn't?

Well I'm supposed to be ready to lose all history. Coz right now the actual code is already different than on the git..

Comment: Forking a repo creates a new repo. Your question about publishing to Digital Ocean is a separate issue and you should contact their technical support team to resolve that.

Comment: Yes, I just need to clarify it before execute. off course for DO problem I will contact them.

So when I do forking then it will goes to my repo? then from git desktop I will pull from the fork repo?

Comment: No - after you fork the repo you will need to change your deployment to use your *new* forked repo.

Comment: And yes, from your desktop you will also change your settings to use your *new* forked repo.

Comment: @Reza Please mark this as the answer if your question is resolved.

Comment: one more, is it means when doing 'fork' I will  still use the same private repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148809/discussion-between-steveland83-and-reza).